# Jquery .attr(attrname) doesn't always work?

Tags: java, jquery, html, dom

I have to get an attribute value in a js script.
While I was using the Jquery method elem.attr() to retrieve that value,I noticed that in some case, that method doesn't work.
For example:

```
<li value="1409079461">
```

If I call $(this).attr("value") on this element, it returns the right value,but

```
<li value="100001794127456">
```

If I call the method on this last element, that has an attribute with more digits, .attr("value") returns 0.

Does anyone know the reason of this strange behaviour? Is there a limit on the amount of data that the method can handle?

Comment: I can **not** reproduce this on Chrome 12, OS X. Maybe a browser specific issue?

Answer (score 3):

value of `LI` is integer, and max integer is 2,147,483,647, everything else will be 0

Comment: also "The value attribute is deprecated, but still supported in all major browsers.", something to think about going forward

Answer (score 2):

I did not know but I checked in W3C recommendations and seems like `<li/>` nodes can have `value` attribute which should be a [number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-number) as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), but it is marked as *deprecated*. So as others (@Ivanov and @Digbyswift) mentioned it will be converted to a number.

I've checked an example code with jsFiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUvJZ/) and it's actually working in Safari, but I won't use `value` attribute if you don't really need to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't work.

However it isn't valid HTML.

If you use data attributes it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/f75LT/

```
<ul>
    <li data-value="1409079461">Test1</li>
    <li data-value="100001794127456">Test2</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).data('value'));
    });
});
```

Comment: It does not need to be valid HTML for jQuery to pick up the attribute. Also, the data suffix is HTML5 specific but I understand where you're going.

Comment: @Digbyswift. Thats what I said `I don't know why it doesn't work`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is attempting to convert the value to an integer, tha value is too large and it is defaulting to zero.

If you need this value, then I would suggest placing an underscore character at the beginning to force jQuery to consider this a string. You can then strip the underscore afterwards.